DynamoDB query works on CLI but not in Lambda: "Value null at 'key' failed to satisfy constraint"
On the CLI this works:
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name BatchTable \
    --index-name completed_index \
    --key-condition-expression "completed = :completed" \
    --expression-attribute-values  '{":completed":{"N":"0"}}'

Result:
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "completed": {
                "N": "0"
            },
[snip]

But in Lambda this doesn't:
import { DynamoDBClient } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';
import { DynamoDBDocumentClient, GetCommand } from '@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb';
const ddbClient = new DynamoDBClient({});
const ddbDocClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(ddbClient);

const ddbCommand = new GetCommand({
    TableName: 'BatchTable',
    IndexName: 'completed_index',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'completed = :completed',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':completed': '0',
    },
});

const ddbResponse = await ddbDocClient.send(ddbCommand);

Result:
1 validation error detected: Value null at 'key' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null

I can't for the life of me figure out why.

As is often the case when I post a question here, I figured it out minutes later. Stupid mistake actually, I should have been using QueryCommand and not GetCommand. Changing to:
const ddbCommand = new QueryCommand({
    TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
    IndexName: 'completed_index',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'completed = :completed',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':completed': '0',
    },
});

.. resulted in a new error:
One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type which was resolved by removing the quotes around the value 0, as it's a numeric value in the table.
Anyway, I'll leave this here in case it helps someone else.
